# ImportError: libSM.so.6 when using setuptools in setup.py

Tags: python, opencv, importerror

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, when trying to import cv2, I get the following error:

```
  /mnt/jenkins/workspace/project/client/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/opencv_
  python-3.4.0.12-py3.5-linuxx86_64.egg/cv2/__init__.py"()

      7 
      8 # make IDE's (PyCharm) autocompletion happy
 ---->9 from .cv2 import *
      10 

 ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such 
 file or directory
```

I am using setuptool and my setup.py looks like this:

```
setup(
   name="Modulename",
   version="0.1.0",
   packages=find_packages(),
   install_requires=["numpy", "matplotlib", "tqdm", "opencv-python"],    
 )
```

In my requirements.txt file I have:

```
   opencv-python == 3.4.0.12
   numpy == 1.14.2
   matplotlib == 2.2.2
```

There are questions on the same topic but they solve the problem with

```
apt update && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6
```

For me, import cv2 works in the terminal and locally in Pycharm but not through Jenkins, when setup.py is used. 
Any help will be welcomed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use opencv-python-headless package instead of opencv-python. it's out of libSM6 dependency.

`pip install opencv-python-headless`